# Help, Genius pen sketch 9*12 tablet on Ubuntu 14.04 ! NOT WORKING

Tags: 14.04, graphics-tablet

I tried to use my **Genius pen sketch 9*12 tablet** on **Ubuntu 14.04**, but all the solutions out there didn't seem to work,

First it seems there is no wizardpen release for ubuntu 14.04, am i wrong ?!

Second, my tablet's light is responding to both mouse and pen, none of them moves the pointer but only the mouse can click with the 3 buttons and even scrolls !, However when i use the command lsusb in the terminal it detect a new hardware but doesnt identify it as a tablet "first line" :

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5543:0008 UC-Logic Technology Corp.
Bus 002 Device 053: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c18 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

is there anything i can do to solve this ? any idea? Thank you, your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Any help please ?!

Answer (score 0):

Wizardpen really isn't recommended anymore. The [DIGImend project](http://digimend.github.io/tablets/KYE_PenSketch_M912/) works to support Tablets at the driver level. If you're willing to join the [mailing list](http://digimend.github.io/support/#maillist) they may be able to help you, or work with you to get the tablet working.